# Find out if a user shared this page on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook's share button is deprecated but still many sites uses it. Is there anyway I can subscribe to a share event (or other clever hack) so I can find out if a user shared a page, without extended permissions, like you can do with the like button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a click event to the fb-root (or the iframe fb generates) element and do some ajax-magic to count it (or send it to google analytics)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're suggesting